# Missing 'logs below' during start of a Node.js app in Micro CloudFoundry

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry

I have locally a instance of Micro Cloud Foundry.
I deploy a node.js app who failed to start.

Every things seems to be ok. Vm player and micro cloudfoundry are ok.
I connect with vmc to my instance.

I create (or share) 2 services : a redis and a mongoDB. That I link to this app.

And when I start (or update), i had an Error.

This error should be show me some logs. ('below') but it doesn't.

An Idea about that ? Thanks

(the standard answer (according from google) is /logs/sterr.log or other. But I haven't.

Moreover, Where is the /logs/ directory ?

```
toto@toto:~/apps/myapp$ vmc update myapp
Uploading Application:
  Checking for available resources: OK
  Processing resources: OK
  Packing application: OK
  Uploading (7K): OK   
Push Status: OK
Stopping Application 'myapp': OK
Staging Application 'myapp': OK                                            
Starting Application 'myapp': .
Error: Application [myapp] failed to start, logs information below.
toto@toto:~/apps/myapp$
```

Comment: Did you ask this question (about your app failing to start) at CloudFoundry support forum? To view the list of available logs, you should use `vmc files %your_app_name` command ([more here](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/debugging.html)).

Comment: Hi you can view all log and application files by using the "files" command on VMC. So, to view /logs/sterr.log it would be "vmc files myapp /logs/strerr.log". If you just pass in a folder name, VMC will list all the files in that folder.

Comment: In fact, the command 'vmc files myapp' give me first an error.
'No such File or Directory'

Then the next start take especially a long time. Don't deploy app.
So I haven't the strerr.log.

Comment: If you are willing to share the source code for this I will happily try to provision it myself to see whats happening at start up.

Comment: Yes of course. You can get my code app on http://github.com/mycozycloud/cozy-notes

Comment: I'll try to install Cloud Foundry OSS and set the app in the end of this week. Try to see if i have the same issue